# How to add taxonomy to node of custom type when taxonomy field name is unknown?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

If field name is known it easy:

```
$node->field_{taxonony_field_name}[$node->language][0] = array('tid' => $term->tid);
```

What if name is unknown?

I found some examples which using this construct:

```
$node->taxonomy = $term;
```

but in my case it just wasn't work.

Comment: `$node->taxonomy = $term;` is Drupal 6 code if I remember rightly. In Drupal 7 you need the name of the field, but you might be able to get them from somewhere. Can you expand on your scenario a bit?

Comment: I have to migrate data to many content types. I even don't know most of this content types right now. Every content type field for taxonomy has a different name (probably), so it will be easier to me without need to know about this field name